# What's the best way to subsample a ZMQ PUB SUB connection?

Tags: sockets, zeromq, publish-subscribe, sample

I have a ZMQ_PUB socket sending messages out at ~50Hz. One destination needs to react to each message, so it has a standard ZMQ_SUB socket with a while(true) loop checking for new messages.  A second destination should only react once a second to the "most recent" message.  That is, my second destination needs to subsample.

For the second destination, I believe I'd want to have a time-based loop that is called at my desired rate (1Hz) and recv() the latest message, dropping the rest.  I believe this is done via a ZMQ_HWM on the subscriber.  Is there another option that needs to be set somewhere?

Do I need to worry about the different subscribers having different HWMs?  Will the publisher become angry?  It's a shame ZMQ_RATE only applies to multicast sockets.

Is there a best way to accomplish what I'm attempting?

---

zmq v3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The HighWaterMark will not be a fantastic solution for your problem. Setting it on the subscriber to, let's say, 10 and reading 1 message per second, will just give you the old messages first, slowly, and throw away all the new, because it's limit are reached.

You could either use a topic on you publisher that makes you able to filter out every 50th message like making the topic `messageCount % 50` and subscribe to `0`.

Otherwise maybe you shouldn't use zmq's pub/sub, but instead do you own look alike with router/dealer that allows you to subscribe to sampled messages.

Lastly you could also just send them all. 50 m/s is hardly anything in zmq (if they aren't heavy on data, like megs) and then only use every 50th message.

Comment: I'm new to SO, so maybe there's a better way to respond, but I found a solution that works for my needs (though perhaps not ideal).  

I added an intermediate object that subscribed to every message, storing the most recent to a member variable, and periodically re-published whatever happened to be stored last.  I have both cpp and python implementations.  Then, wherever I want to receive sampled data, I instantiate this object in front of it and spin it.  The destination doesn't notice any difference in content, only rate.

Comment: Interesting solution. Do you have multiple `intermediate objects` or consider having multiple of them?

Comment: There's nothing preventing me from having multiple "rate limiting" objects.  I could deploy them in front of every end point, or as one-to-many republishers for any end point that requires a specific rate (one running at 100Hz, another at 50Hz).

I'm happy to post the code.  Do I do that here in a comment, or do I edit my question?

Comment: I think I would be easier to add it as an edit to the answer. Otherwise reference a gist.